# Programmatically add claim to a list

Tags: sharepoint-2010, claims-based-identity

I wrote a small piece of code which add a claim to a site in Sharepoint.
I proceed like that :

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url)) 
        { 
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            { 
                SPClaimProviderManager claimMgr = SPClaimProviderManager.Local; 
                if (claimMgr != null) 
                {
                    SPClaim claim = new SPClaim(type, claim_name, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimValueTypes.String, SPOriginalIssuers.Format(SPOriginalIssuerType.ClaimProvider, provider)); 
                    string userName = claimMgr.EncodeClaim(claim); 
                    SPUserInfo info = new SPUserInfo 
                    { LoginName = userName, 
                        Name = name }; 

                    SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(info.LoginName, info.Email, info.Name, info.Notes); 
                    roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(web.RoleDefinitions["Read"]); 
                    web.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment); 
                    web.Update(); 
                } 
            } 
        }
```

Pretty easy but i would like to add the claim to a list that i created. By now, i'm using SPSite and SPWeb to access the site but i need to go deeper :) and i can't find the way to do ...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both,  `SPWeb` and `SPList`, inherit from `SPSecurableObject` all you have to do is load the `SPList` object for that list you want to alter the permissions.

A `SPList` can be loaded either [by URL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.getlist.aspx) or by [list title](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms443550.aspx):

```
SPList listByTitle = web.Lists["Tasks"];
SPList listByUrl = web.GetList("/server/relative/Lists/Tasks");
```

In your example:

```
        using (SPSite site = new SPSite(url)) 
        { 
            using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
            { 
                SPClaimProviderManager claimMgr = SPClaimProviderManager.Local; 
                if (claimMgr != null) 
                {
                    SPClaim claim = new SPClaim(type, claim_name, Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimValueTypes.String, SPOriginalIssuers.Format(SPOriginalIssuerType.ClaimProvider, provider)); 
                    string userName = claimMgr.EncodeClaim(claim); 
                    SPUserInfo info = new SPUserInfo 
                    { LoginName = userName, 
                        Name = name }; 

                    SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(info.LoginName, info.Email, info.Name, info.Notes); 
                    roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(web.RoleDefinitions["Read"]); 
                    // web.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment); 
                    // web.Update(); 

                    SPList list = web.Lists["TheListTitle"];
                    list.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
                } 
            } 
        }
```

It is not required to update the web or list after the modification of the role assignments.

Comment: wow it's simple ... Sharepoint is very new for me and we asked me to play with claims so that's why i'm lost!
Thank you very much for the help!